# What is the best device for debugging instead of emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to write android application for android mobile devices.I want use Samsung Galaxy tablet when I debugging code.Because tablet is best choice for debugging because screen size bigger than mobile device.

Some android device and tablets use android 4.1.2 .So when I tested in my tablet that use android 4.1.2 ,This program succesfully work on mobile devices right?

In other side is any difference tablet version 4.1.2 and mobile android version 4.1.2 .As a programmer, which device can I use for debugging tablet or mobile devices .Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because tablet is best choice for debugging because screen size bigger than mobile device.

A tablet is a mobile device but if you mean a phone then that is just preference.

> So when I tested in my tablet that use android 4.1.2 ,This program succesfully work on mobile devices right?

No, it means that your program successfully works on Samsung Galaxy tablet 4.1.2. The hardware manufacturers may have other things that will keep your program from working successfully on other devices. A bluetooth module, for example, may be a little different. I have a program which uses Bluetooth communication to another device. It works fine on Galaxy player 4.0 but not on 4.2

> As a programmer, which device can I use for debugging tablet or mobile devices .Is there any difference?

There are differences as I have just explained. The best thing to do is to test on as many devices that you can which could be target devices...this isn't always feasible. I suggest testing at least on a device that uses the same version of Android that you are targeting and one which uses the same minimum version

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference programming fora a phone and for a tablet. You just have to take into account the dimensions. So you should define your dimensions (font sizes) in your res/values folders